# How to make my code take in a function

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm not sure how to make it take in a function. It keeps saying that it's expecting a number.

```
(define (complement f) (cond ((= (comp f (lambda (g) g)) #t) #f)
                             ((= (comp f (lambda (g) g)) #f) #t)))

((complement odd?) 2)
```

Comment: What is `comp`?

Comment: Where does it expect a number?

Comment: comp is    (define (comp f g)
  (lambda (x)(f (g x))))

Comment: it expects a number where the equal sign is

Answer (score 3):

`=` expects numbers as arguments; use `equal?` instead.

Comment: Now it says that ((complement odd?) 2) is not a procedure

Comment: `(complement odd?)` does not return a procedure.